# Can the version of bluetooth on a phone be changed?

Tags: updates, bluetooth

My phone has bluetooth 4.0.   A smart device I purchased requires BT 4.1 in order for the phone to provide BT call and message notifications.  This seems like a software change.  Can I somehow update the bluetooth on my phone?

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you but this is not a "software change".

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've researched further, and my phone, like the "supported" phones, share the following BT specifications:  BT 4.0 A2DP, EDR, LE.  And two of the supported phones add "apl-X".  So if it's not software, is it an actual radio difference?   Where can I research this further?